# How to get multiple fields form into one Json column using ActiveAdmin Active Admin Ruby on Rails and MySQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activeadmin, erb, formtastic

Hi I'm new to ActiveAdmin, it's inherent Formtastic and Ruby (2.6) on Rails (6.1) and need to make a modification on an existing system.

To make it short, I have a Prices model, which is filled with data on a prices.html.erb form.

I need to add key/value pairs (eg: {"fee_1": 10, "fee_2": 20,...}) to be stored in a JSON "fees_list" column, in a MySQL database.

I'm having issues about how to modify the form to input the values.

Amongst many attempts so far, in the prices.html.erb Formtastic form I've tried (Edit: Thanks to Lam Phan for typo fix):

```
<%= f.inputs, for: => :fees_list do |j|  %>
  <%= j.input :fee_1, require: false, input_html: { value: resource.fees_list['fee_1'] } %>
  <%= j.input :fee_2, require: false, input_html: { value: resource.fees_list['fee_2'] } %>
<%= end %>
```

Additional information is that I have a @prices reference available in the prices.html.erb file.

But the resulting page does not display the price inputs. Do I need some Gem to edit/show the JSON data in the DB?

Could someone help please? Thanks a lot to this great community in advance. Best regards!

Comment: i guess the correct syntax should be `f.inputs :for => :fees_list do`

Comment: Thanks @LamPhan.  I updated the question. Now the page does not throw exception but the input fields just don't appear in the page.